# Laravel create new info about errors

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database

In my project I have two tables (category and product) which are connected in relationship. When I try delete category which is assigned to the product, Laravel returned:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`magazyn`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_article_id_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `articles` (`id`)) (SQL: delete
>   from `articles` where `id` = 23)

I know why laravel returns this error but I have a question:
How do I create an information example: "**You cannot delete this category, because it contains products**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors in your query when done via Eloquent should return a `QueryException` object. As such, you can catch it and then parse it to show a message. Of course, that second part is the hard part because there are so many variations of errors, but you might be able to detect common query issues.

For example:

```
try {
    // Run query that might fail here
} catch(QueryException $e) {
   if (stristr($e->getMessage(), 'Integrity constraint violation') {
       return 'Record cannot be deleted or updated because it has related entities!';
   }
}
```

You should know the context of the original query (whether it is an update or delete), so you can probably refine the error message based on that information as well.